# Dynamic Data In Tooltip With Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have a scrolling ticker with dynamic data 
i want that when a user point on that ticker the data according to that information on ticker will show in tooltip with the help of ajax

i tried with the ajax 
but getting an undefined error

here is the ticker code

i want it work like the ticker on

```
www.mcxindia.com
```

i got it i am unable to pass value of $sy to the ajax request

at this line

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getinfo.php?q="+str,true);
```

am unable to pass value of $sy 
please help me

Comment: Honestly, jQuery makes it so easy to do this. You should use that/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the proper answer or not, but I believe all you need to do is to grab the innerHTML of the element on hover, then load that into the tooltip.

You have a function created currently, so we'll work with it.

```
function showUser(str){
 if (str==""){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }else{
   var content = this.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Now we've dropped the ajax and we're just checking what the innerHTML of the object is on mouseover. This allows us to access the data inside of the element in plain-text form.

I don't know what Tooltip you use, plugins etc, but at this point you need to add call the tooltip, and insert our content.

```
function showUser(str){
  if (str==""){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }else{
   var content = this.innerHTML;

  //call the tooltip, add the content to it.
  //because I don't know, I'll assume you have an element with the ID of tooltip
  document.getElementById('tooltip').innerHtml = content;
  }
}
```

The above function grabs the content of the element we hovered over. Then it inserts the data into the tooltip. From here, it's obscure what comes next because I don't know how you create your tooltip. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Good luck!